# ckEditor, change the image class of inserted images

Tags: html, css, textarea, ckeditor, fckeditor

im trying to use ckeditor effectively but need to change the styling of the images it inserts.

Is there a way i can find out what the class is / change it too my own?

I have looked but cant find it and all of the files are minimised and horrible to make sense of.

Craig.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/qdndP/127/ - notice the broken image in the content. Have a look at the source - no ID or class. Then switch to wysiwyg mode, double click the image, click on the right tab (advanced I think in english), enter some values for the ID and Classes, click OK and view the source again. For me it went like this:

[Screenshot of the Finnish image dialog I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE94i.png)

```
<!-- FROM -->
<p><img src="bla.png" /></p>
<!-- TO -->
<p><img class="Magical ponies" id="AwesomeImage" src="bla.png" /></p>
```

If you cannot see those options in your CKEditor, what version are you using and what is your configuration? Also, CKEditor is open source. You can see the sources at https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev - but I don't recommend hacking the core.

Comment: If you need to automatically add a class to the images, the execution depends on your requirements. Do you really want one for all images? Would some other CSS selector be useful for that, like `#Ckeditorcontent img {}`? Or you could use a dataprocessor and do it like the answer for my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257668