# Force CKEditor to add a class to Image2 widget

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I want to configure *CKEditor (version 4.3.2)* to add a class-attribute to every *Image2 widget* figure tag in the content. I use the following code (based on [How to add CSS classes and an ID to paragraphs in CKEditor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257668/how-to-add-css-classes-and-an-id-to-paragraphs-in-ckeditor/12437361#12437361)):

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(e)
{
    var editor = e.editor;


    pClass = 'additional_class',
    pClassRegexp = new RegExp(pClass, 'g');

    editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
    {
        elements:
        {
            figure: function(element)
            {
                // If there's no class, assign the custom one:
                if (!element.attributes['class'])
                    element.attributes['class'] = pClass;

                // It there's some other class, append the custom one:
                else if (!element.attributes['class'].match(pClassRegexp))
                    element.attributes['class'] += ' ' + pClass;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I can add class only for the figure elements having no class 'caption' but then it is not a widget any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CKEditor 4.4 and above, using some configuration options. Here's the relevant instructions from [CKEditor's image2 documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_captionedimage-section-image-alignment-and-classes):

> Thanks to the CKEDITOR.config.image2_alignClasses option introduced in CKEditor 4.4 you can use CSS classes for setting image alignment. Additionally, the CKEDITOR.config.image2_captionedClass option allows you to assign a custom class to the  element of a captioned image....

```
config.image2_alignClasses = [ 'image-left', 'image-center', 'image-right' ];
config.image2_captionedClass = 'image-captioned';
```

> will produce class-driven, stylable markup that lets you avoid inflexible and non-semantic inline CSS code:

```
<figure class="image-captioned image-right">
    <img alt="MyImage" src="myimage.png" />
    <figcaption>MyCaption</figcaption>
</figure>
```